# PHP loses left square bracket in decoded url

Tags: php, laravel, url, decode, lumen

I have a url like this:

> https://example.com/path/to/folder?param[key][=]=value&foo=bar

In the param definition the second key is an operator, which could be gt, lt, =, etc. The problem appears only when the operator is =.

In Laravel/Lumen I cannot parse the query part of the url because somewhere lost the left square bracket. I have tried `urlencode()` instead of `$request->query()` (which gives worst), but the result is the same.

Do you have any idea to get and parse correctly the square brackets definition?

Comment: Replace `=` with `eq` (so equals), not to use special characters for this.

Comment: Yes, `=` is reserved when it comes to query strings.

Comment: _“I have tried urlencode()”_ - but you failed to show us how, exactly … _Obviously_ it is only the `=` character itself here that would need URL encoding, not _anything_ else in that parameter name. `?param[key][%3D]=value&foo=bar` But that would be asking for trouble, if you are not in control of absolutely every single place where such URLs might get generated, or if users try and manipulate it themselves to quickly change a parameter … so using a different “alias” for the operator here, as already suggested, is really the safer way to go.

Comment: Thanks for all comments, you're right. Unfortunately the mentioned url is necessary for one of a third party service, so I cannot change their specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a suitable solution. Laravel's $request->getRequestUri() method gives the full url in the right unencoded format.